# Using Look up map is slower than loading from DB every time? How come?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am facing an issue. Right now, I see our legacy code has a batch insert. Before it, the code do a lot validations. However, one of the thing I think can be improved is in the legacy code, every time we try to load the data from DB and see if it exists. I thought I can load all the table data into a concurrent hashmap at the first time (the first item), but then just check if the record in the map. Here is the code.

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> name2IdMap;

........

public Integer fetchIdByName(String name) {
        if (name2IdMap == null) {
            List<Entity> entities = dao.listAll();
            Map<String, Integer> temp = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getName, Entity::getId));
            name2IdMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(temp);
        }

        return name2IdMap.get(name);
    }
```

However, when I try to insert with 5000 rows, I noticed the cache way is way too slow, which I assume it should be much faster. Can anyone comment on this? Thanks

UPDATE: I log the time and checked it. The map does take effect. More specifically, the first time (loading to the map) takes more time. But after that, it takes 0 ms to find the ID. This does improve the performance when we have more data. However, the problem is after I got this validated value from cache and when I try to fetch another object from DB later (same code), it takes much longer time (from previous 12 ms to now 7s). The code which turn to be slow is

```
public List<M> findByExample(M instance) {
            Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getClass());
            Example example = Example.create(instance);
            crit.add(example);
            List<M> list = crit.list();
            return list;
}
```

By logging, the only step takes too much time is the list(), which I don't know why. Cause the way fetching value from map or db previously seems NOT related to this code. I am using mysql. Now I am thinking if there is something like if you don't keep fetching the db very frequently (ms level), they will put it into "Sleep" mode.

Comment: My guess would be that you're not reusing the object, so `name2IdMap` is null again. Put a breakpoint inside the `if` statement to see if that is so.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not reloading the map every call? Tou haven’t showed the code where the map is invoked.  If you’re creating a new instance in your code the map will be loaded every time

Comment: @Bohemian, I see your point. But I did log the time, starting from 2nd record, validating using map does take 0ms (occasionally 1ms).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of potential reasons,

1. Are you running this piece of code on *multiple threads*? If not, the
   performance for **ConcurrentHashMap** is worse when you use with a
   single thread, but adding more threads to do the work will definitely speed up the process.
2. **ConcurrentHashMap** is much more efficient when you're processing the data with hundreds and thousands of records, with the size of 5000 it will have to do much more work internally to process such smaller dataset.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html